# component onload not fired anymore

Tags: javascript, onload, polymer, web-component

I want to refresh some GUI things after my component is attached and loaded.
I use to do as below:

```
Polymer('research-element', {
  attached: function(){
    var self = this;
    this.onload=function(){self.refresh();};
  },
...
```

But it appears not to work anymore. The callback never get called. I updated both Chrome (32 to 36.0.1985.67 beta on Ubuntu) and Polymer to the latest master.

Any idea why it would not work anymore?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm surprised this ever worked actually. AFAICT, `onload` only fires on certain elements when they have resources (img, iframe, framset, window).

`onload` is an impossible signal to spec for components. It's up to the author to determine when that time is...components can make network requests, query databases, etc. The definition of `load` is hard to pin down.

Depending on what your component does, you could use the `domReady()` callback as the signal for when your element is attached to the document and ready to go. Alternatively, you could use `this.fire('load')` to fire a custom event at the appropriate time when your internal setup is done.

Comment: Yes I was surprised it was working too but I thought this onload might be web-component or polymer related thing. Anyway thanks for the info I'll work around my issue one way or another. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ready event to execute tasks as soon as Polymer is ready.

```
//In Polymer scripts         
  ready: function () {
    ...
  }
```

Or regularly

```
window.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function(e) {
  ...
});
```